# Is the double space after full stops actually wrong?

Tags: periods

I came across a website the other day with an article detailing grammar mistakes that really annoy the writer and how they’ve become so frequently used that people don’t know what’s right and wrong anymore.  One of these was putting two spaces after a full stop. I re-read a couple of times thinking I’d misread but nope, that’s what the writer said.  Now, I’ve always put two spaces, in fact, I was an English language teacher and this is what I taught my students. Surely this isn’t wrong and if I am wrong,
When did this change or have I been wrong all my life?

Comment: Fun fact: Here, including in this very post, multiple spaces are rendered the same as a single space.

Comment: @Laurel true, and it leads to ambiguity, for example if you end your sentence with an abbreviation. I am thinking about companies, as in Acme Corp. Inc.  I am thinking about times, as in 11:30 a.m.  I am thinking about lists, etc.  I therefore prefer double spaces.